# Making a test-stend for debugging a hypervisor

Tags: vmware, intel, qemu, hypervisor

I want to write my own hypervisor for Intel Platform based on an open project and I want understand how to debug it.

I have real stend to debug on, but it reboots at faults and it is hard to find mistake. I've found I could use QEMU/KVM with nested hypervisor to debug it. May be there are any other variants? VMware is hanging with faults, as I understand. On AMD platforms I have used SimNow.
It will be good if the host system will be Windows.

Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your flavor. The couple Qemu/GDB is a good start. Here are some useful hints if your host platform is Intel CPU, you can:

- start qemu like this : `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -s -S ...`.
   Qemu will boot the hypervisor along with its gdbserver and pause it until it receives `continue` command from gdb.
- Start GDB like this: `gdb /path/to/hypervisor` then, `target remote :1234` to attach the gdb to the gdbserver
- Use `hbreak` instead of `break`, but you have only 4 breakpoints left
- From this point, you may continue the debugging as for a simple application